# C# Duration or Length of a media file (Metro)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, media-player

I'm trying to create a media player for the Windows Store. I am using MediaElement to play the file, but I would also like to be able to load multiple songs/videos in a playlist and to display the title of the media file and the length of the file in seconds. 
Something like that:

```
TimeSpan duration = GetFileDuration(mFile.PathToFile);
```

or

```
int durationOfFileInSeconds = GetFileDuration(mFile.PathToFile);
```

How can I do that ? I tried a lot of methods but they don't work because I'm trying do develop for Windows Store. I tried:

1. System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer
2. Microsoft.WindowsAPICodecPack
3. Shell() and GetDetailsOf()
4. many other solutions that I find online

I've also tried to create a new page with a MediaElement just to load files in the MediaElement but the MediaElement.MediaOpened or the MediaElement.MediaFailed events are never fired and while ((mPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan == new TimeSpan())) ; would run indefinitely.

Really need some help with this. I've seen media players on the Windows Store that can display the  duration of the file, so it's possible. I just don't know how.

Comment: @niklon, in general any extensions for music and videos, especially : mp3, avi, mkv, mp4, wmv.

Comment: I think that for every extension the method could be different as data bout the length is stored differently.

Comment: Have you seen this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722501/easiest-way-to-get-mp3-duration-and-size

Comment: @niklon, yes, but I need to reference PresentationCore.dll, PresentationFramework.dll, System.Windows.Forms.dll,System.Xaml.dll and WindowsBase.dll which are not natively supported with Metro UI and if I try to reference them, they generate a lot of errors.